# Who uplifted the humans in David Brin's Uplift novels?

Tags: uplift-universe

Once a long, long time ago I read the cool novel [*Startide Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startide_Rising) by [David Brin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Brin).  [The Uplift saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_Universe) that the novel is a part of is about a universe full of different species.  The only common connection between all these species is that another species made them intelligent, except for humanity.  Other species were gunning for humanity simply because they had no patron.

I didn't read any of the novels after that, and I wonder who uplifted humanity in the saga, or if they weren't uplifted, **what was humanity's origin**?

Comment: [The Eschaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_Sky).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No one, or you're never told. Most of the humans believe that they evolved on their own as a "Wolfling" species, though there are fringes that latch on to various alien civilizations as humanities progenitors...Those are usually cast as somewhat deluded.

If you're going to read more of that series, read *The Uplift War*...It is the best, by far. It's on my "best of all time" list. I also liked *Sundiver*, though that's a bit more of a prequel.

Comment: Its pure class.

Comment: I, personally, really like the second trilogy he did.  The Brightness Reef, Infinity's Shore, and Heaven's Reef trilogy.  I just finished them and they are excellent books.

Answer (score 3):

In the books so far published, no one has been credibly presented as a candidate for the species that uplifted humanity.  The Galactics insist someone must have done it, but we the readers are not necessarily expected to take that as the gospel truth.  It seems that Earth was left fallow for an extremely long time, which suggests that someone (probably in the Migration department) doctored records or manipulated policy to prevent Galactic colonization of Earth.  But that doesn't mean that they interfered in the development of humanity directly.

Comment: Of course, that’s exactly how someone secretly uplifting a species of ape would have covered their tracks.

Answer (score 2):

That’s one of the great mysteries of the series.  To add a bit to the other answers, most of the Galactics believe that the evolution of intelligence is impossible, or that it happened only once, to the Progenitors, who then spread out across the galaxies before it could happen again. To them, humans claiming to have done the same thing themselves is arrogance or even heresy.

Most humans (at least from the educated elite) still think that their species evolved, or aren’t sure, and think the humans who believe they know who their Patrons were are crackpots. At least one group of aliens has started a cult, pretending to be the creators of the human race (which other humans derisively call the Daneks after Erich von Daniken). The one thing we are told for certain is that humans definitely are descended from Earth primates, and were not transplanted from some other world.

This cultural difference becomes important to the plot of several of the books. For example, in *The Uplift War*, because the Galactics do believe in evolution by natural selection, just not the evolution of intelligence, they are able to force the hero to prove that Neo-Chimpanzees have not lost their natural survival instinct. Or, in *Sundiver*,

> One of the villains is plotting to destroy his enemies’ reputation by creating a hoax that will look plausible to humans, but which the Galactic Institutes would dismiss as ludicrous.